# Nice print of python Enum

Tags: python, enums, metaclass

Assume I have the following:

```
from enum import Enum

class Color(Enum):
    RED = 1
    GREEN = 2
    BLUE = 3
```

As the output of `print(Color)`, I want to see:

```
The colors are:
- RED
- GREEN
- BLUE
```

I've tried:

```
from enum import Enum

class Color(Enum):
    RED = 1
    GREEN = 2
    BLUE = 3

    @classmethod
    def __str__(self):
        res = "The colors are:\n"
        for g in set(map(lambda c: c.name, Color)):
            res += '- ' + g + '\n'
        return res
```

But it only works as `print(Color(1))`. How can I have it working when using `print(Color)`?

Comment: I would strongly recommend having that as the output of something other than `print(Color)`. Too much potential for confusion if you have `print(Color)` do that.

Comment: @user2357112 can you outline an alternative solution?

Comment: Write a helper function, or a class method that isn't `__str__`. If you do the thing you're proposing, you'll get confusing results like `print('Object type:', type(thing))` printing `Object type: The colors are:...` when you're trying to get debugging output.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To override printing of the *class*, you could define `__str__` on the *metaclass*:

```
from enum import Enum, EnumMeta

class MyEnumMeta(EnumMeta):
    def __str__(cls):
        lines = [f"The {cls.__name__.lower()}s are:"]
        for member in cls:
            lines.append(f"- {member.name}")
        return '\n'.join(lines)

class Color(Enum, metaclass=MyEnumMeta):
    RED = 1
    GREEN = 2
    BLUE = 3
```

Demo:

```
>>> Color
<enum 'Color'>
>>> print(Color)
The colors are:
- RED
- GREEN
- BLUE
>>> Color.RED
<Color.RED: 1>
>>> print(Color.RED)
Color.RED
```

The class name is discovered:

```
>>> class Animal(Enum, metaclass=MyEnumMeta): 
...     cat = 'meow' 
...     dog = 'woof' 
...     badger = 'grrr' 
...
>>> print(Animal)
The animals are:
- cat
- dog
- badger
```

Comment: Very nice solution

Comment: @wim this looks like what I'm after. Looking a little for documentation around `EnumMeta` yielded very little information. Can you point to any references?

Comment: Seems to be scant info in the docs, but [the `EnumMeta` source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/260ec2c36abd73bac51489108409160427979ede/Lib/enum.py#L122-L516) is very well commented.

Comment: I saw that, but it is still rather cryptic.

Comment: There is no need for specific documentation on EnumMeta - Python is  a very consistent language, and that is just the way metaclasses work - a "class" is, when not used to create new instances, just a normal Python object, and as such, its `__str__` and `__repr__` will be controled by its own class. In this case, this class is EnumMeta. For ordinary classes it is `type`.